# Omnisharp mono fails to load because of "No export was found for the contract 'ILoggerFactory'

Tags: c#, mono, omnisharp

[This issue popped up just today as it was working fine just a day ago.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGs3Q.jpg)

I tried reinstalling mono, visual studio code, rebooting my computer, but nothing worked. This is on the m1 macbook if that makes any difference, but I doubt it has anything to do with the ARM chip...

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/ Mono is going away and so you should use OmniSharp with .NET 6 or 7, https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode#announcements

Comment: I have the same problem and I have installed the last version of .NET on my mac. I still have the same error. What shall I do?

Comment: @LexLi can you reply with the exact procedure for fixing it on macos? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5504#issuecomment-1363581780)'s a temporary fix.

However, all this does is change the version of omnisharp to the lower, default version pinned to the C# extension. It's still unclear why the newer versions are failing.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked. In the past days I've been dabbling around with hooking up Visual Studio with Unity on mac, it did not work. However I came around to try this solution again and it worked magically!